# My codes work well In Dev c++ IDE, but in linux terminal, it doesn't. (especially in the part of 'while' loop.)

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, terminal, putty

```
while(true) {
   getline(myfile, a[i]);
   if (a[i]=="")//or if(a[i].empty())
        break;
    i++;
    n = i;
}
```

In this while loop, when `getline` function gets a blank line from `myfile` object (there is a blank line between a series of binary numbers).

Example:

```
101010
000
11
1
00
                <- when getline meets this line, by "if" break; has to work.
0011
10
00111
1101
```

But, it doesn't realize that blank line.

What is wrong?

What should I code to break when `getline()` meets the blank line?

I do this through PuTTY.

Comment: First of all, what is this `a`? Second, you re trying to find "blank line" in `101010 000 11 1 00`. It has whitespaces not lines.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the while loop to stop when it finds a line with whitespaces?

Comment: @DimChtz that spacing/line breaks was just a formatting issue.  He had attempted line breaks in his post.

Comment: @dckuehn Yes, I see now. Still, what's the definition of `a`?

Comment: Please post minimal working example to reproduce the problem, not just some code from somewhere

Comment: My guess is that you use `char*` instead of `string` thats why `a[i]==""` doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely running into the NL/CR issue.

Instead of

```
if (a[i]=="")
```

Use something like:

```
if (isEmptyLine(a[i]))
```

where

```
bool isEmptyLine(std::string const& s)
{
   for ( auto c : s )
   {
      if ( !std::isspace(c) )
        return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

You can also convert the file into a file with UNIX style line endings by using a utility called `dos2unix`. That should also fix the problem.