# Newline changes how strings read from file are printed in C++

Tags: c++, cygwin, newline, cout, carriage-return

After the text file is read from ifstream to save each line to a vector of strings, it is supposed to be printed out using for loop but it only shows the last line when there is no newline at the end of cout.

I tried the two scenarios to print out the vector of strings:
1) `cout << s;`
2) `cout << s << '\n';`

where s is a string of the vector that iterates every loop.
`1)` only showed the last line whereas `2)` showed the entire text.

```
ifstream inFile("sample.txt");
string str;
vector<string> strings;

while (getline(inFile, str))
    strings.push_back(str);

for (auto s : strings)
    std::cout << s;
```

The sample text is:

```
Test File
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

`cout << s;` only printed:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

`cout << s << '\n';` printed:

```
Test File
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

I expected the second result when executing the first case.
How does newline change the result of output other than the newline itself?

**EDITED**:
Since `getline()` stops when it reaches newline and **does not read** newline either, `cout` without `\n` should have printed `Test FileThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog` ***if*** the program was executed on **Windows**. Because `ifstream` works on **text** mode that converts `\r\n` into `\n`.

However, since I'm using g++ installed on cygwin, that is unlikely to happen. That is the reason why `Test File\r\nThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog` only shows `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`.

Simply put, `\r` makes the output line return to the original point, and that truncated the text before `\r`.

Comment: The first block of code prints everything in one line. There is no reason it would skip any lines.

Comment: @RSahu Unfortunately, it did. I tried it both on Windows and Debian.

Comment: See [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36157885/434551). You are probably facing the same problem as the OP of that question did.

Comment: If you flip lines in your input file, the output wil most likely be `Test File brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.`

Comment: @RSahu Yup. RIght. I just tried once again on linux by creating the exact file with exact text and it worked. The file I used for the test on linux was just copied from the file created on Windows. I think this is because Windows uses `\r\n` for newline and UNIX-like system uses `\n` for newline.

Comment: I've been using g++ installed on cygwin for compilation that might have caused a problem regarding newline. I recreated another exact file using vim on cygwin, and it worked too. The notepad on Windows may have a carriage return conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, text files are generally stored with lines separated by a carriage return (CR) followed by a line feed (LF).  If the file is opened in binary mode, you will get both of those characters when reading in the text.

So `getline`, which splits on the `'\n'` (which is almost certainly the same value as a LF), gives you lines that end in CR (`'\r'`).

When you print a CR, the console may return the cursor to the beginning of the current row.  Then you print the next line and what you originally printed is overwritten.  Since, in your case, the first line was shorter than the second, it made it appear as those the first line was missing.

The problem with that explanation is that

```
ifstream inFile("sample.txt");
```

opens the file in text mode, not binary mode.  So the CR+LF should be reduced to `'\n'` and it *should* work.

Some possible explanations are:

1. The code you've shown is not exactly the same as the code you're using and that `inFile` is actually opened in binary mode.
2. The `sample.txt` file has already been mangled and has lines that end in CR+CR+LF.

Comment: I created a new text file containing `Test\rFile` by using a hex editor and only `File` was printed. I do not use IDE and always compile the code using g++ installed on cygwin. So the conversion from `\r\n` to `\n` might not have happened since it only takes place on non-unix system. Anyway, thank you for letting me remember `\r` is used to return to the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `cout << s << endl;`

Possibly you are using a library, IDE or debugger that sets up `iostream` in order to flush only at new line.

You can try also with `cout << s << flush`, and note that `endl` is like a `\n` character *plus* a flush.